# Blender: Python script fail (creating simple operator)

Tags: python, python-3.x, blender

I'm teaching myself Python in Blender and I attempted to create a simple operator using a script. The script is below - its intention is to select four (spot) lamps in the scene and change their energy (basically, flicking the lights on and off). But when I attempt to run the script, I get a "Python script fail" error message. Can anyone see what is wrong with the code?

```
import bpy


def main(context):
    for ob in context.scene.objects:
        print(ob)

class LightsOperator(bpy.types.Operator):

    bl_idname = "object.lights_operator"
    bl_label = "Headlight Operator"

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.active_object is not None

    def execute(self, context):
        light1 = bpy.data.objects['headlight1']
        light2 = bpy.data.objects['headlight2']
        light3 = bpy.data.objects['headlight3']
        light4 = bpy.data.objects['headlight4']

        if light1.energy==0.0:
            light1.energy = 0.8
        else:
            light1.energy = 0.0

        if light2.energy==0.0:
            light2.energy = 0.8
        else:
            light2.energy = 0.0

        if light3.energy==0.0:
            light3.energy = 0.8
        else:
            light3.energy = 0.0

        if light4.energy==0.0:
            light4.energy = 0.8
        else:
            light4.energy = 0.0

        return {'FINISHED'}

    def register():
        bpy.utils.register_class(LightsOperator)


    def unregister():
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(LightsOperator)

if __name__ == "__main__":
 register()

 # test call
 bpy.ops.object.lights_operator()
```

Comment: Is that the actual indentation?

Comment: I also recommend you, to post questions about blender on [this dedicated StackExchange site](http://blender.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I would recommend learning python outside of blenders specialized python ... blender python is likely to use some things that are considered unpythonic or are counter intuitive.

Comment: I fixed the indentation in your question ... if that was actually your indentation I would take a hard look at that as the culprit

Comment: Joran I copied a new version with your exact indentation into into it and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first issue is indentation (not sure if this changed with the edit) - register and unregister are indented which makes them part of the class which they shouldn't be, un-indent them to make them module functions. This will make the call to register() work so that your class will be available as `bpy.ops.object.lights_operator()`

The main problem is that energy isn't a property of an object, you will find the energy property under data when the object is a light.

```
if light1.data.energy==0.0:
    light1.data.energy = 0.8
else:
    light1.data.energy = 0.0
```

Some other improvements you could make -

In the poll function you could be more specific. Instead of just having something selected, check that it is close to what you want.

```
return context.active_object.type == 'LAMP'
```

Instead of re-typing the same code for every object you can use a loop and a test to use the same code for every object. This could leave you with this shorter script -

```
import bpy

class LightsOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "object.lights_operator"
    bl_label = "Headlight Operator"

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.active_object.type == 'LAMP'

    def execute(self, context):
        for object in bpy.data.objects:
            # object.name[:9] will give us the first 9 characters of the name
            if object.type == 'LAMP' and object.name[:9] == 'headlight':
                if object.data.energy == 0.0:
                    object.data.energy = 0.8
                else:
                    object.data.energy = 0.0
        return {'FINISHED'}

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(LightsOperator)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(LightsOperator)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()

# test call
bpy.ops.object.lights_operator()
```

Comment: I do believe that new poll function has fixed it! Thank you sambler!